# Override BigDecimal to_s default in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, default, bigdecimal

As I retrieve data from a database table an array is populated.  Some of the fields are defined as decimal & money fields and within the array they are represented as BigDecimal.

I use these array values to populate a CSV file, but the problem is that all BigDecimal values are by default represented in Scientific format (which is the default behaviour of the BigDecimal to_s method).  I can show the values by using to_s('F'), but how can I override the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built on @Farrel's answer, but without polluting the method namespace with a useless `old_xyz` method. Also, why not use default arguments directly?

```
class BigDecimal
  old_to_s = instance_method :to_s

  define_method :to_s do |param='F'|
    old_to_s.bind(self).(param)
  end
end
```

In Ruby 1.8, this gets slightly uglier:

```
class BigDecimal
  old_to_s = instance_method :to_s

  define_method :to_s do |param|
    old_to_s.bind(self).call(param || 'F')
  end
end
```

Or, if you don't like the warning you get with the above code:

```
class BigDecimal
  old_to_s = instance_method :to_s

  define_method :to_s do |*param|
    old_to_s.bind(self).call(param.first || 'F')
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried this code, but got "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.' on the define_method line

Comment: @Skoppensboer: Optional parameters with default arguments for blocks is a Ruby 1.9 feature. As is the `block.(foo)` syntax. In Ruby 1.8 you have to use a different solution for supplying the default argument and you need to use the `call` method.

Comment: Thx Joerg, thought it may be the case, but guys I'm trying to help out is still on 1.8.7

Comment: Hi, any idea why would I get a `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)` when using this code? Not just with your 3 examples, any attempt of redefining to_s fails with that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BigDecimal
  alias old_to_s to_s

  def to_s( param = nil )
      self.old_to_s( param || 'F' )
   end
end
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks Farrel & David, I knew this should be possible, just didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Please don't do this. It unnecessarily pollutes `BigDecimal`'s namespace with a completely useless `old_to_s` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby makes this easy.  Behold:

```
class BigDecimal
  def to_s
    return "Whatever weird format you want"
  end
end

# Now BigDecimal#to_s will do something new, for all BigDecimal objects everywhere.
```

This technique is called monkey patching.  As you might guess from the name, it's something you should use cautiously.  This use seems reasonable to me, though.