# Any override for rspec errors on BigDecimal?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, bigdecimal

Big Decimal's `to_s` prints as scientific notation.

rspec uses the `to_`s for error messages.

How could rspec be monkey-patched so that it prints errors for BigDecimal using a more conventional formatting?

This relates to this question: [Override BigDecimal to_s default in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335034/override-bigdecimal-to-s-default-in-ruby)

But I don't want to globally override `BigDecimal.to_s`.

Answer (score 2):

This works. Create file in rspec/support/big_decimal_inspect.rb

```
# Monkey patch BigDecimal#inspect
# Otherwises test errors print like:
# expected: #<BigDecimal:108482700,'0.11E3',9(27)>
#     got: #<BigDecimal:108468080,'0.12E3',9(27)>
# After get:
# expected: 110.0
#      got: 120.0
class BigDecimal
  def inspect
    to_s
  end
end
```